# Moodle clears cache when upgrading database, won't let database upgrade

Tags: php, caching, moodle

Logging in as the administrator takes me straight to the unskippable Plugins screen which forces me to upgrade Moodle's database. As soon as I click Upgrade Database, the screen goes blank with the url ending in `index.php?confirmplugincheck=1&cache=0`

Then if I refresh the page, I get an error. Moodle can't access the contents of `moodledata/cache` because the upgrade deleted them. If I copy the contents from my backup into `moodledata/cache`, the site works fine, but takes me to the unskippable Plugins screen again.

The error:

> Warning:
> require_once(C:\Moodle\server\moodledata/cache/locallib.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Moodle\server\moodledata\cache\disabledlib.php on line 34
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\Moodle\server\moodledata/cache/locallib.php' (include_path='C:\Moodle\server\moodledata/lib/zend;C:\Moodle\server\moodledata/lib/pear;.;C:\Moodle\server\php\PEAR') in C:\Moodle\server\moodledata\cache\disabledlib.php on line 34

Moodle version: 2.9+

Answer (score 2):

Could you try to purge the cache from the command line, before the upgrade, see if that works.

```
php admin/cli/purge_caches.php
```

https://docs.moodle.org/29/en/Administration_via_command_line#Purge_caches

If it doesn't then in config.php what are the values for `dataroot` and `dirroot`?

Also what version of Moodle are you upgrading from?

UPDATE: also insert these lines into config.php

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 0);

$CFG->debug = E_ALL | E_STRICT;
$CFG->debugdisplay = true;
```

Comment: $CFG->dataroot  = 'C:\\Moodle\\server\\moodledata';
There's no dirroot. Upgrading from version 2.9+.

Comment: locallib.php won't be in the moodledata directory, so something has gone wrong there. Try adding `$CFG->dirroot = ` and the root folder of the moodle site. Also what version are you uprading from?

Comment: Also add the debug lines above

Comment: Upgrading version 2.9+

Comment: The script worked fine, but by purging the cache I get the same "couldn't find file from the cache folder" error.

Answer (score 1):

Had same problem, resolved by

```
$CFG->dataroot  = '/home/moodledata';
$CFG->dirroot  = '/home';
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the
$CFG->dataroot
was pointing to
$CFG->wwwroot
entry folder as well. So i then created **moodledata** folder outside my moodle entry folder and then pointed my
$CFG->dataroot
to it. The upgrade went okay.